Nginx Configuration Issue: Hiding Subdirectory from URL and Serving Root Directly
I'm trying to configure Nginx to serve my application without exposing a subdirectory in the URL. My application files are located in a subdirectory (ddformbuilder), but I want the URLs to appear as if they are served directly from the root domain without the subdirectory being visible.
Current Setup:
Domain: https://app.example.com
Application Directory: /var/app/current/ddformbuilder/
Desired URL: I want URLs like https://app.example.com/login.php instead of https://app.example.com/ddformbuilder/login.php.
Current Nginx Configuration:
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app.example.com;

        root /var/app/current/ddformbuilder/;

        index index.php;

        location / {
          root /ddformbuilder;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/app/current/ddformbuilder;
        }
      }


Even with this configuration, the URLs still include the subdirectory (ddformbuilder). When I try to access https://app.example.com/login.php, I get a "File not found" error. However, the URL https://app.example.com/ddformbuilder/login.php works fine.
I need the root URL (https://app.example.com) to serve files from /var/app/current/ddformbuilder/ without showing ddformbuilder in the URL path.
What I Tried:

Adjusting the root directive and try_files settings.
Testing different configurations in the location block.
Changing Nginx configuration and reloading Nginx (sudo nginx -t confirms the configuration is okay).


Your configuration is almost correct. You just need to remove root /ddformbuilder; from location.

Tried you solution. Did not work mate
